# How to show related product with main product in different template magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to create accessory category which contain water purifier accessories so when i click on accessory it should display main water purifier with their accessories so i have created main product A which is water purifier and also created A1,A2,A3 product as related product of product A.

Any help would really appropriated.
Thanks.